Why was AlexNet split on two GPUs each of memory size 3GB when it can fit on 1 GB?
In the book 8.1. Deep Convolutional Neural Networks (AlexNet) — Dive into Deep Learning, it claims:

After the final convolutional layer, there are two huge fully connected layers with 4096 outputs. These layers require nearly 1GB model parameters. Because of the limited memory in early GPUs, the original AlexNet used a dual data stream design, so that each of their two GPUs could be responsible for storing and computing only its half of the model. Fortunately, GPU memory is comparatively abundant now, so we rarely need to break up models across GPUs these days (our version of the AlexNet model deviates from the original paper in this aspect).

In the original paper, they simply say

A single GTX 580 GPU has only 3GB of memory, which limits the maximum size of the networks that can be trained on it. It turns out that 1.2 million training examples are enough to train networks which are too big to fit on one GPU. Therefore we spread the net across two GPUs.

So I wanted to calculate exactly how much memory it should take.
The network has 60 million parameters and 650,000 neurons in float32 format. It was trained by momentum gradient descent with batch size 128. So, during training, each parameter corresponds to 3 parameters (the parameter itself, the gradient, the momentum). That gives 180 million parameters, or 720 MB.
It also need to store the activation patterns of 128 images, so that gives $0.65 \times 128 = 83$ million parameters, or 332 MB.
That gives about 1 GB in total, comfortably lower than the 3GB on a single GPU.
Why, then, did they split AlexNet to two halves and claim it does not fit onto a single GPU?

I don't quite see this fitting under History of Science and Mathematics.

I suspect you might get better answers on one of the other sites, perhaps Data Science or even if it is long enough ago Retro Computing. I do not use either of them so I cannot foretell their reaction but I can tell you not to try CrossValidated as it will be closed as off-topic.

What qualifies as historical here should be of at least 50 years past.
